# why is date() function giving a different time to current machine time?

Tags: php, time

Getting a weird output from `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. The result is 5 hours ahead of actual time (time shown on computer). Why is this happening? Where does the `date()` function get its time from? How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Because it is showing server's time zone, if you do not set up a custom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your PHP ini has a default timezone value that's different from the timezone you're expecting.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php